# What would be the best way to create such an image

Tags: tables

I saw a figure representing different complex amplitudes in a quantum computer on page 5 in [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eodonnell/quantum15/lecture04.pdf) paper. Here is an image :
[image]

As you can see, the structure is matrix-like with different lines, equations and text elements. I do not have a lot of experience in the design of such elements, I only have used packages doing this sort of stuff for me. I would like it if someone could point me in a direction to create such a figure. Maybe using a table or matrix package could help ? This is as far as I got !

Comment: I would recommend using TiKz to produce such a figure =)

Comment: Or pstricks is another possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this is by no means a perfect solution, it is a simple start.
Feel free to experiment with the code below, until you achive your desired ouput.

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\def\w{2}
\def\h{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {};
\node (x1) at (\w,0) {};
\node (y1) at (\w,\h) {};
\node[label=below:$\{00\ldots00\}$] (x2) at (2*\w,0) {};
\node (y2) at (2*\w,\h) {};
\node[label=below:$\{00\ldots01\}$] (x3) at (3*\w,0) {};
\node (y3) at (3*\w,\h) {};
\node[label=below:$\cdots$] (x4) at (4*\w,0) {};
\node (y4) at (4*\w,\h) {};
\node[label=below:$x^*$] (x5) at (5*\w,0) {};
\node (y5) at (5*\w,\h) {};
\node[label=below:$\cdots$] (x6) at (6*\w,0) {};
\node (y6) at (6*\w,\h) {};
\node[label=below:$\{11\ldots11\}$] (x7) at (7*\w,0) {};
\node (y7) at (7*\w,\h) {};
\node[label=right:$0$]  (x8) at (8*\w,0) {};
\node[label=right:{$\mu=\text{mean of amplitudes}$}]  (y8) at (8*\w,\h) {};

\draw[thick] (x1) -- (x8);
\draw[dashed] (y1) -- (y8);

\draw [decorate,thick,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
(x1) -- (y1) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] {$\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$};

\draw (x2) -- (y2)
      (x3) -- (y3)
      (x5) -- (y5)
      (x7) -- (y7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is perfect...and happy new year.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I will still have to read the documentation of tikz but this is a great start !

Comment: Hi again, I saw that the vertical lines of the graph did not touch the horizontal lines, is there any way to remedy this ?

Answer (score 5):

Very similar to [N3buchadnezzar's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/577182/232027) yet with some means to avoid duplicating explicit coordinates.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[dashed] (0,1.5) coordinate (tl) -- ++ (8.5,0) coordinate (tr)
    node[right] {$\mu=\text{mean of amplitudes}$};
 \draw 
  (0,0) coordinate (bl) -- (tr|-bl) node[right] {$0$}
  [nodes={alias=last,below,text height=2ex,append after command={-- (tl-|last)}}]
  (1,0) node{$\{00\dots00\}$} 
  (2.75,0) node{$\{00\dots01\}$} 
  (5,0) node{$x^*$} 
  (7.25,0) node{$\{11\dots11\}$};
 \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,raise=0.4ex}] (bl) -- 
 node[left=0.8ex]{$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$}(tl);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice also this answer...and also for you a good and fantastic 2021.

Comment: @Sebastiano Mille grazie! [Happy New Year](https://topanswers.xyz/image?hash=b7ce9dca644a3844ff8d02bf2ecd9703dff2f980280db0bd6bf15d8aede2e036)

Comment: Your talent it is very clear :-) everywhere. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I will still have to read the documentation of tikz but this is a great start ! Even though reducing the size os not that important for me, I will try to understand this more compact notation. I hope you will understand that I validate the first answer for a more explicit understanding.

Comment: @Jonathcraft Sure! (This is certainly not compressed, e.g. the second `\draw` command can be condensed to `\draw 
  (0,0) coordinate (bl) -- (tr|-bl) node[right] {$0$}
  [nodes={alias=last,below,text height=2ex,append after command={-- (tl-|last)}}]
  (1,0) node{$\{00\dots00\}$} 
  (2.75,0) node{$\{00\dots01\}$} 
  (5,0) node{$x^*$} 
  (7.25,0) node{$\{11\dots11\}$};`.)

Comment: Hi again, I saw that the vertical lines in N3buchadnezzar's answer did not touch the horizontal lines, is there any way to remedy this ?

Comment: @Jonathcraft Yes, use `\coordinate` instead of `\node` for all the involved vertices. E.g. `\coordinate (A) at (0,0);`. As far as I can see you can replace all the `\nodes` before `\draw[thick] (x1) -- (x8);` by `\coordinate`s.

Answer (score 4):

A solution with  `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border = 6pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-node, pstricks-add}
\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.5)(15.2,1.5)\footnotesize
\pnodes{A}(0,1.2)(1,1.2)(3,1.2)(7,1.2)(11,1.2)(12,1.2)
\pnodes{B}(0,0)(1,0)(3,0)(7,0)(11,0)(12,0)
\pcline[linewidth=0.5pt, linestyle=dashed, dash=4pt 2pt, nodesep=1pt](A0)(A5)
\pcline[nodesep=2pt](B0)(B5)
\multido{\i=1+1}{4}{\psline(A\i)(B\i)}
\uput[d](B1){$\{00\dots00\}$}\uput[d](B2){$\{00\dots01\}$}\uput[d](B3){$x^*$}\uput[d](B4){$\{11\dots11\}$}
\uput{2ex}[d](5,0){$\dots$}\uput{2ex}[d](9,0){$\dots$}
\uput[r](A5){$\mu=$ mean of amplitudes}\uput[r](B5){$0$}
\psbrace[singleline, linewidth=0.5pt, braceWidthInner=2pt, braceWidthOuter=2pt, nodesepA=-14pt, nodesepB=7pt](A0)(B0){$\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]